# Should login be allowed if we can't cd to the home directory? (login.defs configuration)

Tags: login, pam

While reading through the `/etc/login.defs` configuration file, I found the following entry:

```
# Should login be allowed if we can't cd to the home directory?
# Default is no.
DEFAULT_HOME    yes
```

This was how my file was configured on Ubuntu 18.04.
Is "yes" a secure setting for this?

I can't find very much documentation after researching this, and I'm interested to know why my system wouldn't have the default setting.

Comment: I've never explored this option, but I'm betting if the default is YES, GUI will be unable to login anyway (same issue as no disk space in $HOME); but a quick scan of a local debian box shows the same default there too.

Comment: ... and non-graphical login will dump the user into `/` (with a message like *"No directory, logging in with HOME=/"*